# Apps Script (Google Sheet) - How to customize the fotmat in a concatened string?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet and I need to concatenate in only one cell the values of different cells in the spreadsheet. But I need to set format bold to only some of the values.
I write an example of what I need:

```
A1= Tom
B1= White
C1= 1/1/2000
```

```js
function exampleFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var name = sheet.getRange('A1').getValue();
  var surname = sheet.getRange('B1').getValue();
  var dateOfBirth = sheet.getRange('C1').getValue();
  sheet.getRange('D1').setValue(name + ' ' + surname + ', born ' + dateOfBirth);
}
```

The result in cell D1 is:
Tom White, born 1/1/2000

But I'd like to set the bold format only to the name (A1) and the surname (B1), as following:
**Tom** **White**, born 1/1/2000

Does anyone have any idea how I can do it?

I tried the following code but it doesn't work:

```js
function exampleFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var name = sheet.getRange('A1').getValue();
  var surname = sheet.getRange('B1').getValue();
  var dateOfBirth = sheet.getRange('C1').getValue();
  sheet.getRange('D1').setValue(name.setBold(true) + ' ' + surname.setBold(true) + ' ' + dateOfBirth);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a RichTextBuilder to format portions of the text in the cell.  Rather than use all the variable names you use I know that `values[0][0]` is the first name and so on.

```
function test() {
  try {
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    let values = sheet.getRange("A1:C1").getValues();
    let bold = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setBold(true).build();
    let value = values[0][0]+" "+values[0][1];  // only the name for now
    let length = value.length;  // now I know how many characters have to be bold
    value = value+", born "+Utilities.formatDate(values[0][2],"Z","MM/dd/yyyy");
    value = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
            .setText(value)
            .setTextStyle(0,length,bold)
            .build();
    sheet.getRange("D1").setRichTextValue(value);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

Reference

- [RichTextBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value-builder)
- [RichTextBuilder.setTextStyle()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value-builder#setTextStyle(Integer,Integer,TextStyle))

Comment: If this is the answer please mark it so others with similar question can find an answer.  And I get "ata boy points".  Thanks.